# Postgres: How to use value of field in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have db table like this:

```
id | user | service |   pay_date   |   status

---+------+---------+--------------+------------

1  | john |    1    |  2014-08-20  |     1    
2  | john |    3    |  2014-07-24  |     0
```

I am trying to build query which return all users who are not payed service 1 or service 3 between 2 dates and haven`t active services (status = 0 for service 1 and service 2). The problem is that query return service 3, but this is not correct because service 1 is active.

```
SELECT * 
FROM services 
WHERE date > 2014-07-01 
  AND date < 2014-07-30 
  AND service = 1 OR service = 3
```

My solution is to check if service 3 is active when i`am checking service 1. Something like that...

```
SELECT * 
FROM services 
WHERE date > 2014-07-01 
  AND date < 2014-07-30 
  AND ((service = 1 AND "SERVICE 3 IS NOT ACTIVE") OR service = 3)
```

but i cant check if "SERVICE 3 IS NOT ACTIVE" for current user

Comment: The problem is in the logic, this queries are just for example. This query return service 3 but service 1 is active. I want to get only users who haven`t active services now but they has active service in this period

Comment: two words: self join

Comment: try with `status = 0 where service = 3` at the place of `"SERVICE 3 IS NOT ACTIVE"`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? After reading a couple of times it is still not clear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want NOT EXISTS, i.e. checking that another active record does not exist for the same user, possibly something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM    Services
WHERE   Service IN (1, 3)
AND     pay_date > '2014-07-01'
AND     pay_date < '2014-07-30'
AND     NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    services AS s2 
            WHERE   s2.Name = s.Name 
            AND     s2.Status = 1 
            AND     s2.Service IN (1, 3)
            AND     s2.pay_date > '2014-07-01'
            AND     s2.pay_date < '2014-07-30'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single record that meets all those criteria.

id 1 record cannot be both service = 1 & service = 3 at the some time

```
id | user | service |   pay_date   |   status
---+------+---------+--------------+------------
1  | john |    1    |  2014-08-20  |     1
```

id 2 record cannot be both service = 1 & service = 3 at the some time

```
id | user | service |   pay_date   |   status
---+------+---------+--------------+------------
2  | john |    3    |  2014-08-24  |     0       -- nb: I changed this date!
```

SO: your criteria require comparing record 1 to record 2 (or more broadly, that you have to compare "across records"). below I use `EXISTS` to compare across records.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM services
WHERE (pay_date >= '2014-08-01'
      AND pay_date < '2014-08-30')
      AND service = 1
      AND EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  NULL
            FROM services s3
            WHERE (s3.pay_date >= '2014-08-01'
                  AND s3.pay_date < '2014-08-30')
                  AND s3.service = 3
                  and s3.status = 1
                  AND s3.user = services.user
                 )
```

see <kbd>[SQLfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/93c0f/3)</kbd>

---

by the way, it is more conventional to use a date range via >= & <